# Error on PHP Form with json decode after AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

After much research and confusion I've decided to ask on here.

Basically, I can make my AJAX request post in every way except JSON. I'd like to learn it so I can just start from JSON instead of learning it down the road.

The **PHP code** below errors

> Undefined index: data

What am I missing?

Here's the **.serializeArray() & JSON Stringyfied** console string:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "client_id",
        "value" : "111"
    }, {
        "name" : "project_id",
        "value" : "222"
    }, {
        "name" : "user_id",
        "value" : "465605"
    }, {
        "name" : "utl_latitude",
        "value" : "40.6110589"
    },{ 
        "name":"utl_longitude",
        "value":"-111.8999353"
    },{
        "name" : "utl_event",
        "value":"CLOCK IN"
    }, {
        "name" : "utl_action",
        "value" : "FOLLOW UP"
    }
]
```

The **AJAX request** to the best of my knowledge

```
// START AJAX REQUEST ---------------------------------------------------------------------------        
$.ajax({

    url: 'test.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: url_parameters,
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 5000, // Longer than 5 seconds? HTTP SERVER or PHP Offline.***

    beforeSend: function () {

        self.status_please_wait();

    },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        /* PHP PDO MySQL Insert Status --------------------------------------------------

        return 0 = Nothing to Update (***Disable for Select & Insert)
        return 1 = Successful Insert Query
        return 2 = Database Connection refused
        return 3 = MySQL Query Error OR Wrong URL Parameters */

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // If data return 0 = Nothing to Update
        // Placeholder for future mysql Update

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // If data return 1 = Successful Insert Query
        if (textStatus === 'success' && data === '1') {

            //self.php_pdo_mysql_insert_status(data);

            self.status_insert_success();

        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // If data return 2 = Database Connection refused
        if (textStatus === 'success' && data === '2') {

            //self.php_pdo_mysql_insert_status(data);

            self.status_mysql_connection_refused();

        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // If data return 3 = MySQL Query Error OR Wrong URL Parameters
        // Placeholder for future mysql error 3

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    },
    // END SUCCESS function ---------------------------------------------------------

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // NIGX offline or PHP offline.

            // If http server and/or PHP is/are offline...
            if (errorThrown === 'timeout') {

                self.status_http_php_offline();

            }


        }
        // END ERROR function ---------------------------------------------------------

});
// END AJAX REQUEST -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The PHP on the server side:**

```
<?php

    $decoded = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);

    foreach ($decoded as $value) {
       echo $value["name"] . "=" . $value["value"];
    }

?>
```

**The PHP error**

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: data in **F:\Wnmp\html\mysql_post_json\test.php** on line **9**
>       
>       **Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **F:\Wnmp\html\mysql_post_json\test.php** on line **11**

Comment: What's the value of `url_parameters`? The problem is most likely there. If you're sending the json you mentioned above, you would need to to write something like `data : { 'data' : url_parameters }`. Then PHP will be able to get the variable using `$_POST['data]`

Comment: is it that your foreach needs to be `foreach($decoded as $key=>$value`?

Answer (score 0):

At last, the answer.

```
<?php

// First get raw POST input
$raw_post     = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Run through url_decode..
$url_decoded  = urldecode($raw_post);
// Run through json_decode...
$json_decoded = json_decode($url_decoded,true);

// Finally access it with foreach
// foreach {"name":"client_id","value":"111"},
//         {"name":"project_id","value":"222"},...
// $json_decoded = {"name":"client_id","value":"111"} each individual of these JSON formated key/value pairs.
foreach ($json_decoded as $column) {
    // Access them.
    // client_id=111
    // project_id=222
   echo $column["name"] . "=" . $column["value"];

}

?>
```